# Difference between expect and expect_any_instance_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-mocks

I have method in my controller that looks like this:

```
def resend_confirmation
  @current_user.send_confirmation_instructions

  render json: nil, status: 200
end
```

I've written following spec for that method:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'POST /api/v1/users/:id/resend_confirmation' do
  let!(:current_user) { create(:user) }

  before do
    expect(current_user).to receive(:send_confirmation_instructions)

    post resend_confirmation_api_v1_user_path(current_user),
         headers: http_authorization_header(current_user)
  end

  describe 'response' do
    it 'is empty' do
      expect(response.body).to eq 'null'
    end
  end

  it 'returns 200 http status code' do
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
  end
end
```

But the problem is that this spec is not passing. This line is failing:

```
expect(current_user).to receive(:send_confirmation_instructions)
```

when I change that to

```
expect_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:send_confirmation_instructions)
```

everything works pretty well. Could someone explain me why spec with expect syntax is not passing?

EDIT:

This how error looks:

```
Failures:

  1) POST /api/v1/users/:id/resend_confirmation returns 200 http status code
     Failure/Error: expect(current_user).to receive(:send_confirmation_instructions)

       (#<User id: 4175, email: "test1@user.com", date_of_birth: "1990-01-01", created_at: "2016-07-18 06:56:52", updated_at: "2016-07-18 06:56:52", sex: "male", touch_id_enabled: false, first_name: "Test", last_name: "User", athena_health_patient_id: nil, photo_url: nil, admin: false, one_signal_player_id: "1", phone_number: nil, state: nil, address: nil, city: nil, zip_code: nil, phone_number_confirmed: false>).send_confirmation_instructions(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/requests/api/v1/user/resend_confirmation_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) POST /api/v1/users/:id/resend_confirmation response is empty
     Failure/Error: expect(current_user).to receive(:send_confirmation_instructions)

       (#<User id: 4176, email: "test2@user.com", date_of_birth: "1990-01-01", created_at: "2016-07-18 06:56:53", updated_at: "2016-07-18 06:56:53", sex: "male", touch_id_enabled: false, first_name: "Test", last_name: "User", athena_health_patient_id: nil, photo_url: nil, admin: false, one_signal_player_id: "2", phone_number: nil, state: nil, address: nil, city: nil, zip_code: nil, phone_number_confirmed: false>).send_confirmation_instructions(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/requests/api/v1/user/resend_confirmation_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: can you try expect(User.find(current_user.id)).to receive(:send_confirmation_instructions)?

Answer (score 3):

`expects(...)` sets the expectation on a particular instance. When the POST request is executed, your app will try to identify the user referenced in your request information, and will create an instance that represents it.

However, that instance is not the same you prepared in your test. It indeed references the same user object, but it's not the same Ruby object.

Therefore, inside your tests, the `current_user` that is used is not the one you set the expectations on.

Using `expect_any_instance_of` instead affects every instance of user created, hence also the one that will be created to satisfy the request.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what was happening to me. Verified it by testing `foo.object_id` in the spec and also within the countroller.